# how i can send textarea value to web-Services?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

i trying to use this text area and two buttons to send the textarea value to web services what i can do to call the methods from web services ?? can i call if from `onclick""` or i must put it in the `form` and what i need to have else of web services link to this project done below is my code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div style="width:300px; height:100px;">
        <div style="width:300px; height:80px;"></div>
        <div style="width:300px; height:20px; background-color:#7C728E;"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="width:300px; height:70px">
        <textarea style="width:300px; height:70px; resize: none;" name="tb" type="text" maxlength="500"
        placeholder="Enter text message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div style="width:300px; height:70px; background-color:#7C728E;">
        <div style="width:87px;margin-left: 3px;">
          <input id="cancel" onclick="****" type="button" value="CANCEL"
          style="background-color:#7C728E;margin-left: -4px; color:#FFFFFF;" />
        </div>
        <div style="width:72px; margin-left: 215px; margin-top: -25px;">
          <input id="send" onclick="*****" type="button" value="SEND"
          style="background-color:#7C728E;margin-left: -4px;color:#FFFFFF;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all if you want to send all data a form is a good thing to use, second how you want to send i, with AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div style="width:300px; height:100px;">
        <div style="width:300px; height:80px;"></div>
        <div style="width:300px; height:20px; background-color:#7C728E;"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="width:300px; height:70px">
        <textarea style="width:300px; height:70px; resize: none;" name="tb" id="tbContent" type="text" maxlength="500"
        placeholder="Enter text message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div style="width:300px; height:70px; background-color:#7C728E;">
        <div style="width:87px;margin-left: 3px;">
          <input id="cancel" onclick="return submitData('0')" type="button" value="CANCEL"
          style="background-color:#7C728E;margin-left: -4px; color:#FFFFFF;" />
        </div>
        <div style="width:72px; margin-left: 215px; margin-top: -25px;">
          <input id="send" onclick="return submitData('1')" type="button" value="SEND"
          style="background-color:#7C728E;margin-left: -4px;color:#FFFFFF;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script language="javascript">

 function submitData(isSubmit) 
{
var Msg = $("#tbContent").val();
   if(isSubmit==1)
   {
              $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../WebService/yourfile.asmx/yourmethodname",
            data: "{'Msg':'" + Msg}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d > 0) {

                        alert("Data saved successfully.");

                }
            }
        });
   }
   else
   {
      //do your cancel job here
    }
}



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a form. and than this code should work:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function( e ) {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'form.php', // change to the right file
                data: postData,
                success: function () {
                  //do function on success
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

EDIT:
You also need to change the semd button to `type="submit`
js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BcBM5